# Grails: domain properties are mandatory by default and Id is not generated

Tags: grails-domain-class

I am new to Grails. I installed Grails 2.4.4 version and Spring Tool Suite. 
I created Grails project and domain ,controller classes. But i am getting all the fields as mandatory by default and "id" is not generated. Need some help.

Domain Class:

```
package org.example.pomorodo

class Task {

String summary
String details
Date dateCreated
Date deadLine
Long timeSpent=0L 
    static constraints = {      
    }
}
```

Controller Class:
    package org.example.pomorodo

```
class TaskController {
   static scaffold =Task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't access the "id" property after saving your domain object with GORM?  Or just that the generated code doesn't have an "id" property explicitly defined?  If it's the latter, don't worry.  The "id" property is automatically injected by metaprogramming black-magic by the framework.  If it's the former, something else is wrong, as you should definitely have a valid "id" after saving a domain object.

On the mandatory fields:  Use the constraints block to toggle fields to nullable = true.  Example:

```
package org.example.pomorodo

class Task {

String summary
String details
Date dateCreated
Date deadLine
Long timeSpent=0L 
    static constraints = {      
       summary(nullable:true)
       details(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

You can also modify default constraints globally.  See the [constraints documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got a query regarding mapping a database table which do not have any id and version. For example the table have two varchar fields username and password nothing more than that.
Although it was something strange for me that table doesn’t have the id field. The good thing is that the username is a primary key in the table and this is not auto incremented user want to create it by his own method.
The good thing about grails is, in most of the cases you get your answer in the docs http://grails.org/doc/latest/ . So in this case we just need to change the id field in grails domain like this

class Test {
    String username
    String password

```
static mapping = {
    id name: 'username'
    version false
    id generator: 'assigned'
}
static constraints = {
    username(nullable: true)
}
```

}